# On .submit alert if $.get returns a certain value

Tags: jquery

I have a problem with the code below. I can't get it to popup the alert on submit. Well the only way I got it to work was by inserting another alert outside of $.get. (you can see it below). I'll be more than thankful for any help and guidelines I might get.

```
$('#addEvent').submit(function() {
    var date = $('#day').val();
    var startTime = $('#startTime').val();

    $.get("/cal/check-For-Existing-Events/time/"+date+"%20"+startTime+":00/room/1234", function(data) { 
        if(data == "Error: date") {
            alert('Error: This date has expired.');
            return false;
        }
        else if(data == "Error: existing") {
            alert('Error: You already have a reservation made on this day.')
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    });
        alert('test');  //If I remove this part, above errors don't work. WTH!?
});
```

Comment: The `return` statements in your `$.get` callback aren't doing what you think they are doing - they're simply returning from the `$.get` callback function and not from the submit handler. The form will most likely always submit, except for when you add that last alert, which will delay it long enough for the `$.get` to execute.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wait for ajax validation to complete before submitting a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866654/how-to-wait-for-ajax-validation-to-complete-before-submitting-a-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your suggestions. I tried all of them but none of them seemed to work. That's why I decided to start from scratch using some of the information I got from previous answers.

Below is the code that works. + I also have to add, that **I had to remove the submit button from the form and make another one outside of it** for code to work. I Don't really know why, so if anyone has any information on this.. do tell. :)

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
    var timeStamp = $("#day").val()+" "+$("#startTime").val();
    var room = $room ?>
    $.post("/cal/check-For-Existing-Events/time/"+timeStamp+"/room/"+room, function(data) {
        if(data == "Error: date") {
            $("#errorDisplay").html("Select future date.")
            $("#errorDisplay").show();
            return false;
        } 
        if(data == "Error: exists") {
            $("#errorDisplay").html("You already have a reservation.")
            $("#errorDisplay").show();
            return false;
        }else {
            $("#addEvent").submit();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I hope that this answer will be helpful to anyone. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var ready = false;
$('#addEvent').submit(function() {
    if (!ready) {
        var date = $('#day').val();
        var startTime = $('#startTime').val();

        $.get("/cal/check-For-Existing-Events/time/" + date + "%20" + startTime + ":00/room/1234", function(data) { 
            if(data == "Error: date") {
                alert('Error: This date has expired.');
            } else if (data == "Error: existing") {
                alert('Error: You already have a reservation made on this day.');
            } else {
                ready = true;
                $('#addEvent').submit();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This look like a viable answer to me. No @RobHruska they wont because he's using a boolean flag variable to determine if the forms ready to submit, first loop is false so the ajax call gets made.  If the `.get` request returns no errors then the flag is set to true and the submit handler is invoked again.

Comment: Thats why you need to disable the form submit button while the ajax is running. When ajax returns and there is no error enable the submit button or just submit the form using js.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a param "e" and e.preventDefault();

$('#addEvent').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
        var date = $('#day').val();
        var startTime = $('#startTime').val();

```
    $.get("/cal/check-For-Existing-Events/time/"+date+"%20"+startTime+":00/room/1234", function(data) { 
        if(data == "Error: date") {
            alert('Error: This date has expired.');
            return false;
        }
        else if(data == "Error: existing") {
            alert('Error: You already have a reservation made on this day.')
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    });
        alert('test');  //If I remove this part, above errors don't work. WTH!?
});
```