# jQuery Wait for Ajax Before Submitting Form

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have three Ajax functions I would like to complete before a form is submitted, but they are also triggered on submit.

What would be the best way to force jQuery to wait until all Ajax functions complete before the form is sent? My code is as follows:

```
$('form[name="regForm"]').on('submit', function() {
    ajaxFuncOne();
    ajaxFuncTwo();
    ajaxFuncThree();
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to wait for ajax validation to complete before submitting a form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/866654/how-to-wait-for-ajax-validation-to-complete-before-submitting-a-form)

Answer (score 4):

1. First stop the submission (using `e.preventDefault();`),
2. Then wrap your ajax calls in a `$.when()` function,
3. Then submit the form.

Don't forget to unbind the `on('submit')` listener functionality before submitting, else you will end up in an infinite loop (as `submit()` will be triggering `on('submit')`, which will be triggering `submit()`, and so forth).

Like so:

```
$('form[name="regForm"]').on('submit', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.when(
        ajaxFuncOne();
        ajaxFuncTwo();
        ajaxFuncThree();
    ).done(function(){
        $('form[name="regForm"]').unbind('submit').submit();
    });
});
```

See https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/ for more information on $.when().

Answer (score 0):

Define a counter variable for tracking how many ajax functions have succeeded, in the scope accessible to all functions. Let's assume it's called `c`. Then, prevent submission if it is not equal to three. Disable the button  to avoid further clicks.

```
$('form[name="regForm"]').on('submit', function() {
  if(c < 3) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
    ajaxFuncOne();
    ajaxFuncTwo();
    ajaxFuncThree();
  }
});
```

Then call the following in each success handler.

```
function track() {
  if(++c == 3) $('form[name="regForm"]').submit();
}
```

Only when all three have succeeded, will the form be submitted.

Comment: This will result in an infinite loop; when `track()` is called and the `if(++c == 3)` condition is satisfied, it will indeed submit the form - which though will again trigger the `on('submit')` event listener, which will again execute `e.preventDefault();`, and the ajax functions, etc.

Comment: I added a check for that.