# Function returning before Ajax completes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ajax

I have a problem whereby my submit event sometimes completes without waiting for the ajax call.  I really don't understand what is going on here.  Sometimes it seems to wait, and I get the success and done messages, and other times it fires the submit action without waiting and loads the next page.

```
function SetUpAjax() {
    $.ajaxSetup({
        data: "{}",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json"
    });
}

function SaveBooking(booking) {
    $.ajax({
        url: HOST + "api/SaveBooking",

        data: JSON.stringify({
            booking: booking
        }),
        success: function(resdata) {
            alert("SaveBooking Saved")
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    SetUpAjax();
});



function Generate() {
    if ($('#addbookingaction').valid()) {

        try {
            var booking = GetBookingFromForm()
        } catch (err) {
            alert("error" + err)
            return false
        }

        $.when(SaveBooking(booking)).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("Booking Saved")
            return true
        }).fail(function(data) {
            alert("Save Booking failed")
            return false
        })
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

// Pug html
input(type = "submit", id = "save", name = "save", value = "Save", onclick = "return Generate()")
```

My understanding is that the "when" call should wait for the SaveBooking ajax function to complete before returning either true or false.  However, it seems that the Generate function sometimes returns true before the Ajax has had a chance to execute, thus I don't get the "Saved" alerts. When I check the server response, it is always a response success.

If I put return false at the bottom of the Generate function, then I always get my "Saved" alerts, but the page doesn't exit as onclick event returns false.

I feel like I am going mad here.  I can't understand why the behaviour would be inconsistent (maybe a race condition?).  Can anyone be of help?

Comment: The form submission redirects the page before the request has completed. See e.g. [jQuery Wait for Ajax Before Submitting Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43326088/jquery-wait-for-ajax-before-submitting-form)

Comment: That'll do it. Thanks.